# iOS 8 Custom Keyboard appear pretty slow

Tags: ios8

I am trying to build a custom keyboard using Swift for iOS 8 and I created each button programatically. When switching to my custom keyboard from build-in keyboard, the first time it's pretty slow as it took like 2 seconds to appear. I am not entirely sure if I am doing it correctly. Below are my code and I just show 2 buttons but there are a lot more:

```
class KeyboardViewController: UIInputViewController {

    @IBOutlet var nextKeyboardButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var qButton: UIButton!

    var buttonFontSize:CGFloat = 22.0
    var gapBtwButton:CGFloat = +7.0
    // a lot more button below

    override func updateViewConstraints() {
        super.updateViewConstraints()

        // Add custom view sizing constraints here
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupEnKeyboard()

    }


    func setupEnKeyboard(){

        println("setupEnKeyboard")

        addEnKeyboardButtons()

    }

    func addEnKeyboardButtons() {

        addQButton()

        addNextKeyboardButton()

        // a lot more button to be added

    }

    func setupButton(label: String, functionName: Selector, imageOnButton: String) -> UIButton {

        // initialize the button
        let keyButton:UIButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(.System) as UIButton

        var testVar: String? = imageOnButton

        if imageOnButton.isEmpty {

            keyButton.setTitle(label, forState: .Normal)

        } else {

            let image = UIImage(named: imageOnButton) as UIImage

            keyButton.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)

        }

        keyButton.sizeToFit()
        keyButton.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

        // adding a callback
        keyButton.addTarget(self, action: functionName, forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

        // make the font bigger
        keyButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(self.buttonFontSize)

        // add rounded corners
        keyButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1)
        keyButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
        keyButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5

        return keyButton

    }

    func addQButton() {

        qButton = setupButton("Q", functionName:"didTapQButton", imageOnButton:"")

        view.addSubview(qButton)

        var leftSideConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: qButton, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: +6.0)

        var topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: qButton, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: +10.0)

        view.addConstraints([leftSideConstraint, topConstraint])

    }

    func didTapQButton(){

        var proxy = textDocumentProxy as UITextDocumentProxy

        proxy.insertText("q")

    }


    func addNextKeyboardButton() {

        nextKeyboardButton = setupButton("N", functionName:"advanceToNextInputMode", imageOnButton:"globe")

        view.addSubview(nextKeyboardButton)

        var leftSideConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: nextKeyboardButton, attribute: .Left, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: showNumbersButton, attribute: .Right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: self.gapBtwButton)

        var bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: nextKeyboardButton, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -3.0)

        view.addConstraints([leftSideConstraint, bottomConstraint])

    }    

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated
    }

    override func textWillChange(textInput: UITextInput) {
        // The app is about to change the document's contents. Perform any preparation here.
    }

    override func textDidChange(textInput: UITextInput) {
        // The app has just changed the document's contents, the document context has been updated.

        var textColor: UIColor
        var proxy = self.textDocumentProxy as UITextDocumentProxy
        if proxy.keyboardAppearance == UIKeyboardAppearance.Dark {
            textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        } else {
            textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        }
        //self.nextKeyboardButton.setTitleColor(textColor, forState: .Normal)
    }

}
```

Appreciate any comment please :)

Thanks,
Mark Thien

Comment: I have the same problem. Extension seems to be pretty slow whilst debugger doesn't show any peak in usage.

Comment: Please have a look at the log messages on the iPhone (XCode -> Window Menu -> Devices). I got some fancy error messages here. You, too? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26827639/ios8-keyboard-extention-advancetonextinputmode-leads-to-odd-error-message

Comment: same trouble here, how to speed up load with custom keyboard?

Comment: We're having some serious problems with that, including the keyboard not loading at all sometimes. Our research seems to point to Apple's frameworks as it 'seems' we never get to our 'viewDidLoad'. But, it's been really difficult to trace as the Xcode debugger fail to attach itself to the keyboard many times. We are looking hard for any clues as to what happens when touching a textField result in a complete stall (nothing happens, nothing pop up).

Comment: @bauerMusic do you think any solution will speed up custom keyboard speed? like make cache for UIButton, or write an custom UIButton?

Comment: @TomSawyer The 'solution' for now seems to be revolving around keeping the keyboard as 'light' as possible. Although inconclusive, it seems that a keyboard that does very little (including light on resources) will jump up faster. Also, beware of the App Group's shared UserDefaults. It seems to be leaking and adding a healthy chunk to the memory consumption. We mistakingly loaded it up. The shared 'container' (`containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier`) is the right place to share heavier resources. Think memory diet.

Comment: @bauerMusic how about to use `dispatch_get_global_queue` to lazy create UIView ? I want to speed up the first initial display and render child UIControls after. Is it possible?

Comment: @TomSawyer Sure is. Matter of fact, we started down that path at the time. That was exactly where it was heading. Let a 'light' view load and load heavier things asyncly using GCD.